# DayZ Requirements

Tags: dayz-2012, arma-2

I want to play the mod version of **DayZ**, but only have / want to have **ARMA 2**.

[The **DayZ** site](https://dayzmod.com/?About) lists the requirements for the mod as:

> Requirements:
>
> - ArmA II: Combined Operations
> - DayZ Mod Files (Available on the downloads page)

If I buy **ArmA 2** and download **ArmA 2: Operation Arrowhead** (demo) instead of just owning the Combined Operations package (which contains 2 and Operation Arrowhead), would I be able to play the **DayZ** (mod)?

Comment: Cant see a downvote reason here.. However i dont think that you could play dayz just with the arrowhead demo

Comment: I was not asking if i can play it with just the arrowhead.. i was thinking on buyin arma 2 and get the Arma 2 operation arrowhead The Demo... Because on the Arma 2 :Dayz Steam page it says i need Arma 2 and arma 2 Operation arrowhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can have ARMA II and the free version of Arrow head to make the Dayz Mod work.
They only thing you may experience is lower graphics quality, because they don't put the HDR Graphics into the free package.

Don't forget to start each game up so they can register in your system before trying to play Dayz mod.

Wouldn't hurt to update your battle eye also.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to play DayZ with ARMA 2 and the demo of Arrowhead. You need to have launched the full game of both before you can play DayZ.